# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '_'

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, eregi

Following is the regex I am trying to use

```
$eregicheck = "^([-!#\$%&'*+./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~])+@([-!#\$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\$";
```

I changed the following lines

```
return eregi($eregicheck, $emailtocheck);
```

to

```
return preg_match($eregicheck, $emailtocheck);
```

But I dont know why I am getting the error

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '_'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because php requires delimiters before and after the regex pattern, which in your case it assumes to be `^` and after the delimiters follow the modifiers, in your case `_`. Since there's no such modifier hence the error. Change the code to:

```
$eregicheck = "/^([-!#\$%&'*+.\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~])+@([-!#\$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\$/";
```

P.S.: That seems like quite a complex regex, are you sure it can't be simplified? `:P`

Comment: It worked too flawlessly and I did not try simplifying  since it is working properly. Suggest if you can do so.

Comment: @Venky is this regex for validating email addresses?

Comment: Yes. To verify valid email ids

Comment: @Venky well you don't actually need it at all, as `filter_var()` is now around. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: thanks. I never knew it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^([-!#\$%&'*+./0-9=?A-Z\^_`a-z{|}~])+@([-!#\$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z\^_`a-z{|}~]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\$
```

You need to escape ^. It is a special character, which provides instructions to RE.

Comment: You missed one delimiter '^' at the end. Anyways. It worked. Thanks